# How to set-up and configure a ProviderManager using Spring Security namespace?

Tags: java, configuration, spring-security

Spring documentation says that `ProviderManager` is the default implementation of the `AuthenticationManager`, but is an instance of `ProviderManager` automatically created and wired by the security namespace?

In other words, will such configuration automatically create an instance of `ProviderManager`:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
       <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Else, what do I need to do (or declare)?

Assuming I would want to plug my own implementation of `AuthenticationManager`, how would I configure this using the namespace?

I also want to specify which `AuthenticationProvider` should be registered in the `ProviderManager`. I have found the following piece of configuration code:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
            <ref local="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

But is it enough? What is the right way to declare the list of `AuthenticationProvider`? Documentation is not very clear and complete regarding this issue.

Comment: I have posted what I believe to be the correct answer to my questions. I'll give it some time for experts to give their input/feedback if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words, will such configuration automatically create an
>   instance of ProviderManager:

According to section B2 of the appendix, the answer is yes.

> Assuming I would want to plug my own implementation of
>   AuthenticationManager, how would I configure this using the namespace?

According to section B.3.1:

```
<global-method-security authentication-manager-ref="..." >
```

> What is the right way to declare the list of AuthenticationProvider?

From a [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/), instead of using `<authentication-manager> ... </authentication-manager>`, one should use something like similar to this:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="authenticationProvider" />
            <ref bean="anonymousProvider" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="passwordEncoder">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" />
    </property>
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="key" value="SomeUniqueKeyForThisApplication" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

These answers are outdated. Sprinboot3 and Spring security 6 doesnot support these configuration any more

Answer (score 0):

I use the following config with a custom auth providerl;

```
    <authentication-manager>

        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="md5">
                <salt-source user-property="username" />
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" autowire="byType" class="my.user.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userManagementService" ref="userManagementService"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```