# Error creating bean with name 'authenticationmanager' defined in ServletContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I just started to learn Spring Security and have some trouble. I want to configure User login on page with password and username which stored in database. I use Hibernate and spring 4.3 along with MySQL to store data.i was trying to login using DAO Authentication using spring but i'm struck here. please help me out..

**security-context.xml**

```
<!-- custom login Authentication/form -->
        <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" >
            <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasRole('ROLE_STUDENT')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />  

            <form-login login-page="/login"  
                        username-parameter="email" 
                        password-parameter="password"
                        default-target-url="/default"
                        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/index"/>
            <csrf/>
        </http>

        <b:bean id="daoAuthenticationprovider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider" >
            <b:property name="userDetailService" ref="userDetailService"></b:property>
        </b:bean>
        <b:bean id="authenticationmanager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <b:property name="providers">
                <b:list>
                    <b:ref bean="daoAuthenticationprovider"/>
                </b:list>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService">
                <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder> -->
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
```

**Spring-servlet**

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.internbridge" />

    <!-- to prevent browser back button on displaying secure resource after logout -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
<!-- Spring Internationalizations -->   
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="tl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>InternBridge</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring initialization -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/security-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring security configuration -->
    <!-- filter to use spring security, be sure to use suggested name "springSecurityFilterchain"-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Spring MVC or Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**console**

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationmanager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the stack trace, the `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` class does not have a default constructor. You will need to specify the providers when defining the bean. Here is an example.

[How to set-up and configure a ProviderManager using Spring Security namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581058/how-to-set-up-and-configure-a-providermanager-using-spring-security-namespace)